# LibGDX : iOS error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

I am trying out LibGDX on a Mac with the aim to build helloworld for iOS.  It works on Android, Desktop etc.

I am using Android Studio 1.3, I have xcode 6.4 with command line (plus xcode 7 beta 3).  I try to build and run the project and I keep getting.  I have updated to the latest Unity(not sure why that would be needed)

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "2015-07-15 15:13:08.572 xcodebuild[697:11725] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 7FDF5C7A-131F-4ABB-9EDC-8C5F8F0B8A90 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++": error=2, No such file or directory
    at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:302)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:149)
    at org.robovm.compiler.util.Executor.exec(Executor.java:344)
    at org.robovm.compiler.util.ToolchainUtil.link(ToolchainUtil.java:367)
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.AbstractTarget.doBuild(AbstractTarget.java:229)
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.IOSTarget.doBuild(IOSTarget.java:341)
    at org.robovm.compiler.target.AbstractTarget.build(AbstractTarget.java:223)
    at org.robovm.compiler.Linker.link(Linker.java:424)
    at org.robovm.compiler.AppCompiler.compile(AppCompiler.java:462)
    at org.robovm.gradle.tasks.AbstractRoboVMTask.build(AbstractRoboVMTask.java:106)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    ... 79 more
```

Any help would be awesome as I have been searching the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this turns out to be because I have Unity installed and it installs a plugin Unity4XC.xcplugin which messes it up!

Comment: Im getting the same problem, Whats the fit ?

Comment: Anyway of doing this without removing the unity plugin?